# How to process data within .pipe()?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I have a Angular component Typescript function to return an Observable<book[]>. Logic is

```
If (data exists in sessionStorage) Then
    return it
Else
    get it from remote API
    save it in sessionStorage
    return it
End If
```

Implementated as:

```
import { Observable, of, pipe } from 'rxjs';
getData(): Observable<book[]>
{
  var CachedBook = (this.getFromSessStorage("CachedBook") != "") ? 
  JSON.parse(this.getFromSessStorage("CachedBook")) : [];
  if (CachedBook.length > 0)
    return of(CachedBook);
  else
    return this.svc.getBook()  // remote API
    .pipe((b) => 
    { 
      this.setIntoSessStorage("CachedBook", JSON.stringify(b)); // <-- never save data from 
  here
      return b;
    });
}
```

It produces no error, but when data `b` returned it's not saved. There must be something I've not done right inside the `.pipe()`. Function `setIntoSessStorage()` is working fine outside of this function.

Package versions:

```
"@angular/cli": "~14.2",
"rxjs": "~7.4.0",
"typescript": "~4.7.4",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To listen to a stream you use tap, it allows you to cause side effects with the data like storing it in session storage without affecting the stream

```
return this.svc.getBook().pipe(
  tap(b => { this.setIntoSessStorage("CachedBook", JSON.stringify(b)); })
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `map` operator so your return value is not being put back onto the stream:

```
return this.svc.getBook()  // remote API
  .pipe(
    map((b) => // map here
    { 
      this.setIntoSessStorage("CachedBook", JSON.stringify(b)); // <-- never save data from 
  here
      return b;
    })
  );
```